# location of variables on the stack w/o using (&)

Tags: c++, c, stack, memory-management

I'm trying to determine a way to test the location of variables on the stack (without doing it the common sense way).

```
   int main()
    {
      int i,j;
      return 0;
    }
```

there's really no difference between stating int i; intj; and int i,j;  I can tell by simply cout'ing the addresses.  i goes on the stack, then j goes on the stack.  But is there anyway I could tell this w/o using the memory address operator (or pointers).

this is a specific assignment. Probably so that I can comprehend the reason why the stack is implemented this way.  I can easily determine of how they are located (and yes it's compiler specific but gcc for simplicities sake).

So yes I meant to be doing things the hard way here.. to figure out and demonstrate why and how stacks are implemented in a particular manner

I can add more code, more functions.. whatever.. but the point is to demonstrate the ordering on the stack without the `&`

Comment: If you want "address of" you really should use the "address of" operator...

Comment: The `&` (address of) operator is designed specifically for this purpose so you can obtain pointers to those variables in a portable manner. Why are you actively avoiding the `&` operator? When you need to drive screws, you would use a screwdriver, not your hands!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to find the addresses of local variables without using the C operator designed specifically to find the address of a variable.  Why?

It's worth pointing out that, in any modern compiler/processor combination, the i and j in your example may not be on the stack if you don't use the `&` operator.  Even if you do something with them so  the compiler doesn't optimise them away, it may still choose to put them in registers.

---

**Edit:** I've read your comment to datenwolf's answer and I think I know what you are being asked for.  Here is a possible answer, but I must stress that I am making big assumptions about your compiler.  In particular,

- all variables are stored on the stack
- variables aren't optimised away (turn off all optimisations in your compiler).
- storage space for automatic arrays is allocated directly on the stack
- the stack isn't cleaned between function calls

If you have a function like this:

```
int f()
{
    int i = 1, j = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

You can inspect the order of i, j in memory with this function:

```
void order()
{
    int a[2];
    if (a[0] == 1)
    {
        printf("i first\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("j first\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    f();
    order();
    return 0;
}
```

Never use anything like the above in real code.  It relies on several pieces of officially undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think you're very close to what I'm trying to do.. I played with it a little (keep in mind I've never done anything like this prior either).  What prevents me from declaring the variables in main and eliminating the f()?  In this scenario order is reading the variables off the f() stack frame.  Any attempt to declare in main obviously doesn't see the variables properly.   On looking through again.. why is that array yanking off variables from completely separate stack frame.  interesting to say the least.

Comment: This code only works if the contents of the stack are not smashed before the function returns, or if the stack frame setup is randomized. This is a standard technique in cryptographic software and some compilers provide this kind of functionality.

Comment: with a little tweaking I got this to work w/o using pointers.  Very interesting way to do this.

Comment: @datenwolf:  Agreed, I think your point is a variation of my fourth bulleted assumption.

Answer (score 3):

No, you should use the `&` operator to get the variable's address.

Comment: AFAIK, it cannot be done. And the `&` operator is for this purpose.

Comment: @DJPlayer You can't, in C. The variables might be reordered by the compiler, stored in a register, or optimized away, there's no introspection possibilities. And if you do introduce the & operator (which is your only hope), the compiler might generate different code anyhow.  Furthermore.(Although, you could perhaps inspect the generated machine code, or hooking up a debugger and stepping through the code, looking at the assembly)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK There are no guarantees of the ordering in either the C nor the C++ standard. i.e. while you might not detect any differences, there might well be differences when using a different compiler or different (optimization) settings. (in fact the optimizer might also reorder i and j or remove them entirely)

So yes, you need to use "address of". Why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to do this? The location of i and j on the stack are implementation dependent. In fact, in many implementations, i and j won't occupy any space anywhere in your example, because they are never used. The only way to find out for sure is to look at the generated code (which will be different if you use the addresses of your variables).

Answer (score 1):

The language C doesn't even have this concept called a stack. It just defines the behaviour of automatic storage and most compilers implement it using the stack provided by most architectures.

Heck even the `&` operator is purely abstract and the value returned by it, in its numerical representation can be anything, as long as it adheres to the rules of pointer arithmetic. But this number, it may completely virtual and not related at all to the addresses used in the instructions.

So while the task of determining if a variable is located on the stack is well defined, it is, by definition, impossible to implement using pure ANSI C, without resting on implementation specific behaviour. The usual way to carry out this task is by doing a stack walk, provided by functions of the implementations runtime library.

Sorry that I can't be more specific than this. Unlike it's reputation of being a very low level language, C is in fact defined in very abstract terms and many of the programming errors found in C programs stem from this misconception.

Comment: The term would actually be the "activation record".  But most people would comprehend stack better than anything.  Since you at comprehend the architecture the "hint" for this problem is:  2  procedures called from main will use the same storage space on the stack.   I don't see how this could be helpful.  I haven't thought this "hint" through 100% but I'm not seeing the point behind it as of yet.

Comment: @DJPlayer: I think the only proper solution is to look at the assembly, or using some implementation provided stack unwinding methods. I'd prefer the assembly solution.

Comment: if this was a compiler class I'd probably agree.. so I'm imagining there must be some way to do so.. I think the code supplied by JeremyP is on to something.. I just wanna be 100% sure of the inner working of it.  I'm tempted to look at the coding behind the &, but again there must be an easier way..*sigh*